# Is it possible to use the FTD2XX.lib (x64 static) library with MSYS2 application

Tags: gcc, ld, msys2, ftdi

I have a Windows application written using MSYS2 and I need to statically link the FTD2XX library in order to access some FTDI devices.

After much testing and Googling I have failed to be able to have the GCC linker use the FTD2XX.lib library.

Is it possible to use the FTD2XX library from FTDI with MSYS2 (GCC) compiler and linker?

Comment: No, the FTD2XX library is compiled with the Microsoft compiler, and they can't be linked together statically with gcc. But the dynamic library should work.

Comment: Thank you @ssbssa, I have the libraries linked, and yes you are correct one cannot use the statically linked libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your compiler, but I use the D2XX libraries all the time running the Lahey/Fujitsu FORTRAN compiler.  All I need to do is wrapper the paramaeters for C-calls (i.e. explicitly tell the compiler when to pass by value and when to pass by pointer...FORTRAN always passes by pointer).

I would suggest looking at your settings for parameter passing, and make sure that everything matches up.  The D2XX manual is very good at explicitly telling you the expected format for the library calls.   Good luck.